# ContextMenu clipped in some case

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, clipping

I am currently making a context menu which open from left button click instead of right button click and to do that I inhibit the right click by handling the ContextMenuOpening event like this

```
private void PinBorder_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

and I open the context menu by myself on reaction to the MouseButtonLeftDown event like this :

```
private void PinBorder_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = PinBorder;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Center;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset = 0;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.VerticalOffset = 0;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

the problem here is when the ContextMenu is opened the first time everything goes well but if I add an item to the observable collection bound to the context menu and try to reopen it, the context menu is clipped to its previous size (if I try to move the context menu selection with up/down key I can guess that an entry has been created but I can't see it because it is clipped).

I tried to remove the click inhibition stuffs and every thing goes well in that case.

I read about such an issue in .net framework 3.5 but i am targeting 4.0.

Does anyone has a solution ?

Comment: I'm not at a computer where I can test this at the moment, but my first thought is that the context menu control is setup to resize on right-click and that opening it that way doesn't trigger the resize functionality.  Maybe try calling `UpdateLayout()` on your context menu?

Comment: I tried UpdateLayout() and InvalidateMeasure() but nothing changed.

Comment: This is moderately hackish... but perhaps you could open it with a simulated right-click?

Comment: Do you have an idea about how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If finally found a workaround to get what I want even if this solution must allocate more memory than necessary.

I recreate the whole contextmenu each time the context menu must open.

```
private void PinBorder_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    PropertyInputPin.UpdateCompatibleAdjusters();

    PinBorder.ContextMenu = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();

    Binding binding = new Binding("CompatibleAdjusters");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    binding.Source = DataContext;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(PinBorder.ContextMenu, ContextMenu.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

    PinBorder.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = PinBorder;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Center;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset = 0;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.VerticalOffset = 0;
    PinBorder.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < PropertyInputPin.CompatibleAdjusters.Count; i++)
    {
        MenuItem mi = PinBorder.ContextMenu.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as MenuItem;
        mi.Click += ContextMenu_Click;
    }

    e.Handled = false;
}
```

Comment: the problem is still open for a better slution.

Comment: I think this one is a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642910/contextmenu-clipped-in-some-case

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate an event in this fashion:

```
        ContextMenuAutomationPeer peer = new ContextMenuAutomationPeer(Menu);

        IExpandCollapseProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.ExpandCollapse) as IExpandCollapseProvider;

        invokeProv.Expand();
```

Using the UIAutomation isn't simple however (and my example doesn't actually work but should point you in the right direction).

You could also try adding something like this to what you already have (before it in your function):

```
        ContextMenuAutomationPeer peer = new ContextMenuAutomationPeer(Menu);

        peer.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.MenuOpened);
```

[Useful msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741841.aspx).

Comment: I tried the first piece of code and it doesn't work (as you said) because I cannot get pattern return null.
the second piece of code worked but doesn't solve the problem.
thanks for trying. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong.  The following works as desired for me:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="mainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Class1></local:Class1>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Blue" MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown" ContextMenuOpening="grid_ContextMenuOpening">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding menuItems}">
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <Button Height="100" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private List<MenuItem> list;

        public List<MenuItem> menuItems
        {
            get { return list; }
            set { list = value; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            list = new List<MenuItem>();
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "One";
            list.Add(item);
            item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "Two";
            list.Add(item);
            item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "Three";
            list.Add(item);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "Four";
            menuItems.Add(item);
            contextMenu.Items.Add(item);
        }

        private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            grid.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = grid;
            grid.ContextMenu.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Center;
            grid.ContextMenu.HorizontalOffset = 0;
            grid.ContextMenu.VerticalOffset = 0;
            grid.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void grid_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class Class1
    {

        private List<MenuItem> list;

        public List<MenuItem> menuItems
        {
            get { return list; }
            set { list = value; }
        }

        public string test
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Class1()
        {
            test = "1";

            list = new List<MenuItem>();
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "One";
            list.Add(item);
            item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "Two";
            list.Add(item);
            item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "Three";
            list.Add(item);
            TestCommand = new DelegateCommand(Button_Click);
        }

        public ICommand TestCommand{get;private set;}

        private void Button_Click()
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.Header = "Four";
            menuItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm on windows 7.  Do you have a link to other people discussing this problem?

Comment: I tried microsoft forum too : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a1a74dba-81ba-4de8-a72b-69e9e90bce5f
I also found this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/wpf/thread/373c8078-e28d-4b57-8433-d1057d866f62
and this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c9bfa7de-be00-4031-8e67-8999f1c35c91

An interresting thing is that I tried to replicate the bug in another project as you did and everythings worked. It doesn't really help as I don't know what is preventing the contextmenu to extend is my previous case but it's something.

Comment: I think this is an issue specific to your application.  I did some searching around and found the issues that you did but I don't think they're the same as the one you have; they all involve cropping of the side of the context menu rather than not showing the newest item.  My suggestion is to remove parts of your program piecemeal until it starts working, then you will know which part is causing problems.